# Suppressing Some SBCL Debugger Output on Break

Tags: debugging, common-lisp, sbcl

The debugger can be programmatically invoked by executing (break). For example, the debugging banner then displays what caused the interrupt, the HELP line, the available restarts, some related info, and finally the source of the interrupt:

```
debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-CONDITION in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10010B0523}>:
  break

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [CONTINUE] Return from BREAK.
  1: [ABORT   ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

#(
NODE: STATE=<NIL NIL NIL 0.0 0.0
(         )> DEPTH=0)
#(
NODE: STATE=<NIL NIL NIL 0.0 0.0
((ACTIVE GATE1) (ACTIVE GATE2) (COLOR RECEIVER1 BLUE) (COLOR RECEIVER2 RED) (COLOR TRANSMITTER1 BLUE) (COLOR TRANSMITTER2 RED) (FREE ME) (LOC CONNECTOR1 AREA5) (LOC CONNECTOR2 AREA7) (LOC ME AREA5))> DEPTH=0)
(DF-BNB1 )
   source: (BREAK)
0]
```

I don't understand the related info between the restarts and the source. Can this info be suppressed, as
sometimes it is many lines long in my application. I've tried changing the debug & safety optimization settings, but to no effect.

Comment: Do you see that every time you go into the debugger, or just when you use `(break)`?

Comment: I'm not sure what that output is supposed to be. `#(...)` is the representation of a vector, but the contents doesn't look like array elements.

Comment: @Barmar It only seems to appear from inside the program.  Entering (break) or (+ 1 'a) at the REPL gives the normal interrupt without the extra info.  Using SBCL 2.0.0.  Also, the call to (break) is inside a macro.  The expansion seems straightforward: (macroexpand '(when-debug>= 5
    (break)))
(IF (>= `*DEBUG*` 5)
    (PROGN (BREAK)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you are confused with is related to the place in the code where `break` was invoked. When I call it from the vanilla Lisp REPL (without SLIME), it displays:

```
(SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (BREAK) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
```

However, if I do something wrong in the debugger, here's what happens:

```
0] q
; in: PROGN (PRINT 1)
;     (PROGN Q)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: COMMON-LISP-USER::Q
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     Q
;   caught 1 WARNING condition

debugger invoked on a UNBOUND-VARIABLE in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10005204C3}>:
  The variable Q is unbound.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [CONTINUE   ] Retry using Q.
  1: [USE-VALUE  ] Use specified value.
  2: [STORE-VALUE] Set specified value and use it.
  3: [ABORT      ] Reduce debugger level (to debug level 1).
  4:               Return from BREAK.
  5:               Exit debugger, returning to top level.

((LAMBDA (#:G498)) #<unused argument>)
   source: (PROGN Q)
```

You can see that the last line resembles the output you got with the line starting at `source:`. Actually, the output we saw consists of 3 main parts:
1. Description of the condition
2. Listing of the available restarts
3. Debug REPL prompt printed by `debug-loop-fun`

The last output is part of the prompt and it is generated by the invocation of:

```
(print-frame-call *current-frame* *debug-io* :print-frame-source t)
```

So, you can recompile the call providing `:print-frame-source nil` or try to understand why your current frame looks this way...

Comment: OK, thanks for explaining Vsevolod. I now see the printout is displaying the arguments to the function where (break) is located. But still not sure how to inhibit this by setting :print-frame-source to nil, and get the value of `*current-frame*`?

Comment: I studied the code a bit more and saw that there's a `sb-debug::*suppress-frame-print*` variable that seems to be intended to do what you want. So, you can play with it (probably, globally `(setf sb-debug::*suppress-frame-print* t)`. Another option is to monkey-patch `debug-loop-fun`

Comment: Looked promising, but testing with `(defun doit (x) (break) x)` then `(doit #(1 2 3))` still displays full calling environment. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Instead, I've just wrapped the break in a simple function like so:  `(defun break-here () (break))`